# Assign A Value To User Input In Python

Tags: python, variables

I would like to assign a numeric value dependent on user input.

Now would I would like is for the user to type in the 2nd place driver. What ever driver name is typed in would be assigned 2 points for finishing second. Same deal with first place except they get 3 points.

All possible drivers names are set to 0 before the program runs. Those are the possible names the user can type in.

I'm not exactly sure I would do this in Python, and help would be appreciated.

```
Matt_Kenseth = 0
Kyle_Busch = 0
Joey_Logano = 0
Aric_Armirola = 0
Dale_Earnhardt_Jr = 0
Denny_Hamlin = 0
Jeff_Gordon = 0
Brad_Keselowski = 0
Jimmie_Johnson = 0
Clint_Bowyer = 0
Carl_Edwards = 0
Kyle_Larson = 0
Jamie_McMurray = 0
Kevin_Harvick = 0
Kurt_Busch = 0
Ricky_Stenhouse_Jr = 0
David_Ragan = 0
Kasey_Kahne = 0
Danica_Patrick = 0
Ryan_Newman = 0
Casey_Mears = 0
Brian_Scott = 0
Trevor_Bayne = 0
AJ_Allmendinger = 0
Justin_Allgaier = 0
Paul_Menard = 0
Austin_Dillon = 0
Sam_Hornish_Jr = 0
Tony_Stewart = 0
Landon_Cassill = 0
Greg_Biffle = 0
Martin_Truex_Jr = 0
David_Gilliland = 0
JJ_Yeley = 0
Brett_Moffitt = 0
Matt_DiBenedetto = 0
Alex_Bowman = 0
Cole_Whitt = 0
Jeb_Burton = 0
Jeffrey_Earnhardt = 0
Reed_Sorenson = 0
Michael_McDowell = 0
Michael_Annett = 0

int ( input ( "Enter 1st Place Driver In Race.\nThis driver will receive 20 points. " ) )

int ( input ( "Enter 2nd Place Driver In Race.\nThis driver will receive 10 points. " ) )

int ( input ( "Enter 3rd Place Driver In Race.\n This driver will receive 5 points. " ) )
```

I'm very new at programming so sorry if I'm not making much sense. If the user types in one of the drivers listed above for example for 1st place, then I would like that driver to go from 0 to 20 (the value for a 1st place finish).

Comment: How does one set a driver name to 0?  Please clarify in plain English what you are trying to do.  As the question stands, it is very vague.

Comment: Show us your attempt first.

Comment: Your input and int calls are backwards, but if you had run what you have typed, you would know that very quickly

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put all those drivers in a Dictionary with all the values set to 0 ? Something like this:

```
All_Drivers = {"Justin_Allgaier": "0", "Jeb_Burton" : "0"}
```

If you want to change the drivers value you assigned to it based on the user input,here's a very simple example:

```
#Assigning driver names in a dictionary
All_Drivers = {"Justin_Allgaier": "0", "Jeb_Burton" : "0"}

#We're attributing a variable to the user input here
first_place_driver_name = input("Enter 1st place driver\n>")

#Here the for loop is itterating through all the keys in the dictionary and assigning all the keys to the "keys" variable, we can also assign all the values by passing an extra variable
for keys in All_drivers:
    #Now we're using an If statement to check if the name passed by the user matches a key in the dictionnary, if it does, it assigns the value 20 to the correct key.
    if first_place_driver_name == keys:
        All_Drivers[keys] = 20
#Now we're printing all the keys and values in the dictionary.
print(All_Drivers)
```

In this example the first driver received 20points, Try this out with your Driver names, it should work. If you need more information about For loops, If statements and dictionaries check out the Python documentation or search on stackoverflow. To print out a specific value of a key in your dictionary you would need to specify the specific key like this `All_Drivers["Justin_Allgaier"]` .  You might also want to limit what the user can input but i hope this solution can help you.

Comment: I ran the program and selected Justin_Allgaier but it never added the 20, it kept it at 0.

Comment: Very sorry, i added the corrections to the script we shouldn't of had iterated through first_place_driver_name,It's not iterable. Strings are not iterable and a single string shouldn't of had been iterated through anyways. Just wanted to demonstrate how to use For loops to you, and got a bit carried away.